# gdalwarp takes too much time to run

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip

I have 300 m resolution  [ESA Land cover](http://due.esrin.esa.int/page_globcover.php) raster that I want to clip using
the shapefile of Asia. (The shapefile has a border for each country, so therefore not dissolved).

Now I ran this modified code in the clipper:

```
gdalwarp -q -cutline /data/Forest_Extent_Asia_pacific_Ocean_Threats/asian_countries.shp -tr 0.00277777777778 0.00277777777778  -dstalpha -crop_to_cutline
-of GTiff /data/Forest_Extent_Asia_pacific_Ocean_Threats/glob_cover.tif /data/Forest_Extent_Asia_pacific_Ocean_Threats/glob_cover_v2.tif
```

My question is, why does it takes too much time to finish the gdal processing? Is there a bug that caused it?

Comment: how much is too much? can you add more details of the files involved

Comment: Make a test by dissolving and perhaps also simplifying your `asian_countries.shp`. Is it faster then?

Comment: @IanTurton I'm expecting it to finish in 30 min. to one hour, but now I estimated that it would take an overnight for it to finish. I also experienced when clipping vectors, with the input vector with more than 500 features.

Comment: @user30184 yes I will do your suggestion, but I need to wait for my first processing to finish though. =(

Comment: It is up to you but if it seems to take so long it would probably be faster to stop a process and find the good way for doing it.

Comment: in which units is your raster? that 0.0027, if in meters, may really slow your computational time down

Comment: Can you make the write output go to a different physical disk?

Comment: @ElioDiaz all my inputs are in GCS WGS-84, my unit is in degrees,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is to download a country boundaries for asia with a lesser nodes. The country boundaries from GADM (gadm.org) has a much more details that what I got from http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/.

Here are the specific steps:

1) I downloaded the world borders [dataset](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip).

2) Specified only the Asian countries using query builder.

3) Dissolved the country boundaries and saved it as another shapefile.

4) Merged the shapefile in number three with Taiwan (since in country boundary dataset, Taiwan feature is missing).

5) Re-run the gdal code above using the final shapefile in number 4.